# Vue 3, call $emit on variable change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

So I'm trying to build a component in Vue 3 that acts as a form, and in order for the data to be processed by the parent I want it to emit an object with all the inputs on change. The issue I'm having is that I don't seem to be able to call `$emit` from within `watch()` (probably because of the context, but I also don't see why the component-wide context isn't passed by default, and it doesn't accept `this`). I also cannot call any method because of the same reason.

I do see some people using the `watch: {}` syntax but as I understand it that is deprecated and it doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me either.

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Whenever the input date is changed, I want the component to emit a custom event.

```
<template>
  <input
    v-model="date"
    name="dateInput"
    type="date"
  >
</template>

<script>
import { watch, ref } from "vue";

    export default {
        name: 'Demo',
        props: {
        },
        emits: ["date-updated"],
        setup() {
          const date = ref("")

          watch([date], (newVal) => {
            // $emit is undefined
            console.log(newVal);
            $emit("date-updated", {newVal})
            // watchHandler is undefined
            watchHandler(newVal)
          })

          return {
            date
          }
        },
        data() {
            return {
            }
        },
        mounted() {
        },
        methods: {
          watchHandler(newVal) {
            console.log(newVal);
            $emit("date-updated", {newVal})
          }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't mix between option and composition api in order to keep the component consistent, the `emit` function is available in the `context` parameter of the `setup` hook::

```
<template>
  <input
    v-model="date"
    name="dateInput"
    type="date"
  >
</template>

<script>
import { watch, ref } from "vue";
export default {
        name: 'Demo',
        props: {},
        emits: ["date-updated"],
        setup(props,context) {// or setup(props,{emit}) then use emit directly
          const date = ref("")

          watch(date, (newVal) => {
            context.emit("date-updated", {newVal}) 
          })

          return {
            date
          }
        },  
    }
</script>
```

if you want to add the method `watchHandler` you could define it a plain js function like :

```
...
 watch(date, (newVal) => {
            context.emit("date-updated", {newVal}) 
          })

  function watchHandler(newVal) {
            console.log(newVal);
           context.emit("date-updated", {newVal})
          }
...
```

Comment: I'd suggest `setup(props, { emit })`, easier to manage.

Comment: @Juckix context is the second parameter of setup function learn more about it here https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html#setup

Answer (score 1):

How should I do this in setup syntactic sugar

```
const emits = defineEmits(['confirmCallBack', 'cancelCallBack', 'closeCallBack', 'openCallBack', 'update:modelValue'])
const dialogForm = ref<CommonForm >({})

watch(dialogForm.value, (val) => {
  consola.start('数据更新')
  emits('update:modelValue', val)
})
```

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34389326)